# Ternary operator isNaN

Tags: javascript, numbers, boolean

I want to check if 1) a number is even or odd 2) print a message saying "not a number" if the value is not a number. I did with the if else statements but I'm trying to do it with the ternary one for practise, here's the code:

```
function even_or_odd(number) {

  return number % 2 === 0 ? "Even" : number % 2 !== 0 ? "Odd" : isNaN(number) ? "not a number" : "";

}

console.log(even_or_odd(hi));
```

It works for numbers, prints successfully "even" or "odd" but fails in isNaN.

The fiddlestick: https://jsfiddle.net/DimitriXd4/bwfhmqfm/7/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `number % 2 !== 0` is true if `number` is `NaN`, because `NaN % 2` is `NaN` and `NaN` is not equal to 0 (or anything else). Try putting the NaN check first.

Comment: As torazaburo said, use `... number % 2? 'Odd' ...`. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, just check for isNaN first since it is unrelated to other two checks.

```
function even_or_odd(number) 
{   
  return isNaN(number) ? "not a number" : ( number % 2 === 0 ? "Even" : "Odd" );
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, the second statement with the braces really helps to reduce the code. Also do you mind sharing few tips about how to think with Ternary operators and generally logical operators for booleans instead of using if..else, or is it something that comes with practise? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with double or triple nested conditions with ternary operator is you need to encapsulate them. Use it this way:

```
return (number % 2 === 0) ? "Even" : ((number % 2 !== 0) ? "Odd" : (isNaN(number) ? "not a number" : ""));
```

Also add `isNaN(number)` as the first check.

Comment: Actually, none of the parentheses you added are necessary or change the meaning of the expression. Also, if you want to put the `isNaN` check first, why not do so in your sample code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `NaN % 2 !== 0` is true, hence you are seeing result as "odd" even if you pass a value that could be evaluated as `NaN`.

Change your condition from   `number % 2 !== 0` to  `number % 2 === 1` will fix your problem.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yn90v116/)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers, your code is really close, all you need to do is remove the explicit odd test. If both the first two test fail, there's no need for the third, the result must be NaN.

```js
function even_or_odd(number) {
  return number%2 === 0? 'Even' : number%2? 'Odd' : 'Not a number';
}

document.write(even_or_odd('hi'));
```